# Chest freezer / ice bath anti rust protection

Tags: rust, freezer

I've converted my chest freezer to ice bath and the problem I'm facing - it starts to rust in the bottom. What would be the right paint / compound or other protection that I can apply on the bottom to protect it from rust?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Of course remove all water and allow the surface to dry. Apply a rust converter over the rust spots. I have used [Rust Reformer](https://www.harborfreight.com/1025-oz-rust-reformer-spray-paint-67970.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=19231709507&campaignid=19231709507&utm_content=144379160117&adsetid=144379160117&product=67970&store=144&gclid=Cj0KCQjw0tKiBhC6ARIsAAOXutkUWoZ1gh9xYE6_pCcPbX_q39BYuh73NEc-upjbskIUWNMgfiLEIesaAmP9EALw_wcB). No need to sand. The converter need some rust to be present to be effective. It changes the rust on a molecular level to a paintable surface. I have used it on metal steps and on automotive parts and it works.

Then paint with a waterproofing agent such as [AquaDefense](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B088KRVN2G) or [RedGuard](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Custom-Building-Products-RedGard-1-Gal-Waterproofing-and-Crack-Prevention-Membrane-LQWAF1/100169081?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D23F-023_014_FLOOR_TOOLS-NA-NA-NA-PMAX-2996251-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-FLR_TOOLS_PMax_G&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D23F-023_014_FLOOR_TOOLS-NA-NA-NA-PMAX-2996251-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-FLR_TOOLS_PMax_G-71700000102945947--&gclid=Cj0KCQjw0tKiBhC6ARIsAAOXutkVW8n_uCJcITyfJu0gH3M2Fs4rZ2EYhIUPyN0GaXk5i1doO6THM4EaAp0jEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).

The AquaDefense is a pleasant shade of light green. The RedGuard is, as the name implies, red. Both products also work to waterproof the interior of the freezer. Use 2 coats.

I read a review online of Redguard, and the person said they coated a cardboard box with it and filled it with water, placing it on the outdoor deck. Three weeks later they disposed of it because they got tired of looking at a box of water on their deck.  Pretty good proof it works.

Comment: Why wouldn't a person do a little light sanding to restore a smooth surface instead? You'd need to use a primer in some cases, but....

Comment: Do you think it will work with low temperatures? It's filled with freezing water all the time

Comment: @Rainmaker, The RedGuard and AquaDefense are also crack isolation membranes. They are flexible, so I think they would work with ice water. It can be used outdoors but it it is recommended it not be allowed to freeze.  So as long as your water does not turn into an iceblock,  you should be good.